# Embedding in the $d+1$ Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I have heard of the Whitney embedding theorem where any $d$-dimensional manifold can be embedded in $\mathbf{R}^{2d}$. My question is whether the necessity of going up to $2d$ rather than $d+1$ is only due to the global properties of the manifold (e.g. avoiding self intersections) or not?

Here is a more precise statement of what I am looking for:

Take a $d$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ equipped with a metric $g$. For any point $p\in M$ is it possible to choose a neighborhood $U$ containing $p$, and a map $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{d+1}$, where $\mathbf{R}^{d+1}$ is equipped with a flat Euclidean metric $\eta$, and we have the pullback $\phi^* \eta=g$ (restricted to $U$ of course)?

Comment: If you don't care about self-intersections, you can get down to $2d-1$.

Comment: Apparently, for orientable manifolds and non-powers-of-two, you can also get embeddings in $2d-1$ as well, at least if $d>4$. [see here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ojm/1200769312) If $d>4$ is a power of two, it should follow by the same source that there is a non-orientable $d$-dimensional manifold not embedding in $\mathbf R^{2d-1}$. In general, if you have an immersion in an $\mathbf R^{n}$, then by Morse theory it should follow (IIRC) that you have an embedding in $\mathbf R^{n+1}$, so ignoring self-intersections won't help much.

Comment: By the definition of manifold, a small patch can even embed into $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If you are considering isometric embedding, you should cite Nash instead of Whitney.

Comment: @tomasz, thanks for the comment about self-intersections, I wasn't aware of that. Note that global properties like "non-orientable" I don't care about since I am only concerned about embedding an arbitrarily small coordinate patch.

Comment: @JCAA, Sorry if I mixed up my language somewhere. My excuse is I am a physicist not a mathematician. I think what I am asking is something pretty clear though. Is there a map from some coordinate patch about every point to Euclidean space in one extra dimension, such that the pullback of the Euclidean metric is the same as the original metric on the coordinate patch.

Comment: @octonion: So the manifold is equipped with a  metric? Is it a Riemannian manifold? If so then yes, and you do not need an extra dimension.

Comment: You obviously cannot just use the same dimension: if it is the same dimension, then the pullback metric must be flat, which means that your original metric is also flat.

Comment: It is still not clear. Do you want to really have an isometric embedding into $\mathbf R^{n+1}$, or only an isometric isomorphism with a submanifold of $\mathbf R^{n+1}$ (with the intrinsic metric)? The former is usually impossible (essentially, because Euclidean spaces are flat). The latter, as others have noted, is (locally) possible via Nash's theorem.

Comment: @tomasz, I've edited my post to be clearer. I have seen "Nash's theorem" mentioned in the notes, but I have not seen anyone note that this is locally possible in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ due to Nash's theorem. That is precisely what I am looking for, do you mind explaining?

Comment: @JCAA, After some thought I do not think it is possible in the same dimension for precisely the reason Arctic Char mentions. I have edited my post in case it was still not clear after my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the degree of smoothness: In this type of questions you cannot simply say "metric" or "map," you have to specify the degree of differentiability.

1. On the positive side, if all what you care about are $C^1$-smooth maps, then indeed, every continuous metric on an $n$-dimensional $C^1$-smooth manifold can be $C^1$-smoothly locally isometrically embedded in the Euclidean space $E^{n+1}$ (this is a part of the Nash-Kuiper isometric embedding theorem).
2. On the negative side, there are $C^\infty$-smooth metrics on surfaces which do not admit $C^3$-smooth local isometric embeddings in the Euclidean 3-space $E^3$, see for instance:

Nikolai  Nadirashvili, Yu Yuan, [Counterexamples for Local Isometric Embedding](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208127), arXiv:math/0208127, 2002

and also examples of $C^{2,1}$-metrics without local $C^3$-isometric embeddings:

*Nadirashvili, Nikolai; Yuan, Yu*, [**Improving Pogorelov’s isometric embedding counterexample**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00526-007-0140-7), Calc. Var. Partial Differ. Equ. 32, No. 3, 319-323 (2008). [ZBL1147.53017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1147.53017).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation of the naive form of the question and the reference to the counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question about metrics, but as far as global obstructions, go, avoiding self-intersections is not the only one. There's also a classic topological obstruction even to having an [immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)) of a smooth manifold $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^d$ (which is everywhere locally an embedding but may not be injective), which is that the sum of the tangent bundle and the [normal bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_bundle) must be the pullback of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^d$, which is to say, the trivial bundle of rank $d$. (The [Hirsch-Smale theorem](http://math.northwestern.edu/~jnkf/classes/hprin/9euclidean.pdf) implies that if $\dim M < d$ this necessary condition is in fact sufficient to guarantee the existence of an immersion.)

This generally imposes nontrivial conditions on the characteristic classes of $M$; classically it's known (see the Hirsch-Smale link above) that we can find a certain product of real projective spaces of dimension $n$ whose [Stiefel-Whitney classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class) imply that it can't be immersed into $\mathbb{R}^{2n - \alpha(n) - 1}$ where $\alpha(n)$ is the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $n$, and on the other hand [Cohen](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971304) showed that every compact smooth $n$-manifold immerses into $\mathbb{R}^{2n - \alpha(n)}$ so these counterexamples are tight.

A special case, which is a nice exercise, is to take $n = 2^k$ a power of $2$, where we get that $\mathbb{RP}^{2^k}$ does not immerse into $\mathbb{R}^{2^{k+1} - 2}$.

Comment: Thank you, it is interesting to know more about the global obstructions too.